# After updating android studio 3.0 unable to build the project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

android.enableAapt2=false added at the bottom of gradle.properties
gradle.properties

```
http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
    # org.gradle.parallel=true
    android.enableAapt2=false
```

build.gradle
Updated the gradle file after updating sdk tool to 26 version
sdk tool is upto date

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.madhural.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.tarek360.RichPath:animator:0.0.9'
    compile 'com.github.mmoamenn:LuckyWheel_Android:0.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

getting bellow error after build complete

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@mipmap/ic_launcher').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'roundIcon' with value '@mipmap/ic_launcher_round').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@mipmap/ic_launcher').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'roundIcon' with value '@mipmap/ic_launcher_round').
Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme').
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\amin.p\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt.exe with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\amin.p\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar -M \\?\D:\Gamify Your World\GamifyYourWorld\GYWGameApp\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S D:\Gamify Your World\GamifyYourWorld\GYWGameApp\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug -m -J \\?\D:\Gamify Your World\GamifyYourWorld\GYWGameApp\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F D:\Gamify Your World\GamifyYourWorld\GYWGameApp\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\resources-debug.ap_ --custom-package com.example.madhural.myapplication -0 apk --output-text-symbols \\?\D:\Gamify Your World\GamifyYourWorld\GYWGameApp\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug --no-version-vectors}
Error:com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\amin.p\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt.exe with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\amin.p\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar -M \\?\D:\Gamify Your World\GamifyYourWorld\GYWGameApp\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S D:\Gamify Your World\GamifyYourWorld\GYWGameApp\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug -m -J \\?\D:\Gamify Your World\GamifyYourWorld\GYWGameApp\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F D:\Gamify Your World\GamifyYourWorld\GYWGameApp\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\resources-debug.ap_ --custom-package com.example.madhural.myapplication -0 apk --output-text-symbols \\?\D:\Gamify Your World\GamifyYourWorld\GYWGameApp\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug --no-version-vectors}
Error:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\amin.p\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
Information:BUILD FAILED in 13s
Information:10 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: as your error log suggest, double check that all resources are there. The error suggests that you are missing some resource

Comment: `android.enableAapt2=false` comment this line and check.

Comment: After commenting android.enableAapt2=false below error appears.
com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt

Comment: it should download app-compat-v7 : 26 on gradle sync. Can you verify if that has been downloaded?

Comment: First thing when dealing with Android Studio, make sure you are connected to the Internet. Second, as suggested already, Android Studio is telling you that you are missing resources.in the `mipmap` folder and `values/styles.xml` file. So make sure those resources are present. Last, sync gradle if not done then clean the project and finally rebuild it.
If that doesn't work for you, remove the `buildToolsVersion` line and repeat the steps above.

Comment: @Yashasvi Gradle plugins and dependencies are upto date..

Comment: @nt.bas Nothing is missing in project as I have already have mipmap folder etc.
the main error is
Error:org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\amin.p\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: @aminpinjari check your style.xml file have you added like styleable etc.if there is problem in it this error occur.by commenting this part check it is working or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Development\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

This problem is due to this: I have declared the stylable in the `style.xml` which is not correct.

```
<!--<declare-styleable name="mapStyle"><attr name="layout_width"/><attr name="layout_height"/><attr name="layout_weight"/></declare-styleable>-->
```

When I comment it then it works fine.
so check your `style.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifest and style files **very** carefully. There might be errors in them. Specially if you have created your custom styles in styles.xml .

After that Build->Clean Project, and it should hopefully work

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but issue got resolved in accepted answer.