# Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException

Tags: android, gradle, aapt

I have been working on this app for a while and a couple of days ago i came across this error message when I try to build the project:

```
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.3\aapt.exe.
```

Also everytime I use `R`. (for example `R.Drawable`) it says `cannot resolve symbol R`.

I already tried to change the `buildToolsVersion` to the most recent version, added `android.enableAapt2=true` to the `gradle.properties`, cleaning and rebuilding the project but nothing seems to help.

I´ve been trying to solve this problem for a while, I've found a lot of similar questions on StackOverflow, but don't seem to be able to fix it despite of the several attempts to do it. If someone were to help me would very much appreciatted.

Comment: Have you tried clean and rebuild?

Comment: I have, but it didnt work

Comment: Tried the solution here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/47032522/886148

Comment: I have, thanks for sharing